# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: “127.0.0.1

Tags: curl

When I run the `curl http://google.com` in my terminal of my macbook, it always gives me the error: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: “127.0.0.1`. I used to edit my `~/.bash_profile` to add the http_proxy, but I have removed them and closed my proxy and still got this error, does anybody know the reason? Here is what my `~/.bash_profile` looks like now:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: You have a 'smart quote' - check your environment before invoking curl for the proxy variable, also check for a `~/.curlrc` which can define it there also

Comment: I have checked both the ```~/.bash_profile``` and the ```~/.curlrc```, but there is no this werid 'smart quote'.  The ```~/.curlrc``` shows ```socks5 = 127.0.0.1:1087```, and the ```~/.bash_profile``` shows ```export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087``` ```export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087```, so could it be another reason?

Comment: It's probably the `socks5` line; that's the only one that generates the specific `Could not resolve *host*:` line, others have `Could not resolve *proxy*`. check that curl is not an alias (`alias curl`), which can override the curlrc file location. you can check the environment for smart quotes using `env | grep '[“”]'`

Comment: I did as what you said and executed this ```env | grep '[“”]'``` in the terminal, but it showed nothing.

Comment: And I don't have a alias curl in my ```~/.bash_profile```

Comment: The socks proxy setting is coming from *somewhere*. On the presumption that you don't have *any* quotes on the `socks5` line in your `~/.curlrc`, then is it possible that another `.curlrc` file is being read instead?

Comment: If this is the condition, then it is really hard for me to locate the problem cause I have searched a lot and can't find a solution.